# Concept used in the proof

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, logic, proof-techniques, correctness-proof

In the paper ["Resolution for Quantified Boolean Formulas"](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps217/Winter14/Project/Avg/Papers/q-res-kleine-buning95.pdf), I am unable to understand the proof of theorem 3.4. Please help me with the basic concept used on page 4:

[image: theorem 3.4]

The concept that I am referring to is:

> Then $\mathit{\Phi}$ is false if and only if there exists a clause $\phi \in N^+_\mathit{\Phi}$ or $\phi \in N_\mathit{\Phi}$ such that $\forall x_1\exists y_1\cdots y_{k-1}\forall x_k(P_\mathit{\Phi} \land \phi)$ is false.

Comment: That's a badly phrased question. You should try to be more specific about what exactly you find unclear. For starters, *which* concept are you referring to?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: Well, the problem with this question is that in order for anyone to answer it they have to read 15 pages, and for all we know you're just asking for something that was defined on page 3, and you missed it.

Comment: thank you for the reply. yes you are right ,here 15 is the marked page number although its Page 4.

Comment: I have no problem understanding the definitions, but I don't know why the claim you mention is true. Assuming the claim is true, probably after some effort you will be able to prove it. So are you having problems understanding the *concepts/definitions* or why the *claim* is true?

Comment: I have understood the definitions but unable to understand why the claim is true.

Comment: Please try to make the question self contained, not just referring to the paper, but so that one could understand the question without reading the paper.

Comment: @jmite: you don't have to read the paper, it's just the concept in logic which is unclear and I have referred that concept in the question.

Comment: If we don't have to read the paper, then it should be possible to make a self-contained question. This will also be a very good verification for you that you understood the definitions correctly -- trying to explain something to another person is often all that is needed. When I am confused about something I grab a colleague and make him listen, usually I end up explaining the confusion to myself.

Comment: What is $N^+_\phi$? What is $P_\phi$? What is assumed about $\phi$, is it a formula in particular form? Is it in 3rd order logic or 4th order logic? These are the things you should be writing down.

Comment: I assume you were quoting the third paragraph of the proof? I don't see any other text that matches what you typed. I've edited the question to accurately reflect the paper; please advise if I got the wrong part. You may want to review the TeX markup for future reference.

Comment: @TomZych: Thanks for the EDIT! I am looking forward for a satisfying answer now.

Comment: Sorry, @Curious, I'm not familiar with this material. Even those who are familiar with it might not want to wade through enough of the proof to enable them to explain it to you. You should probably read through the whole thing again and try to understand it well enough to ask a more specific question.

Comment: @Curious: The claim makes no sense without the definitions and setup, so you need to copy them into your question.  A reference to a paper isn't enough if you want people who might be able to answer your questions to take time and help you.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Re explaining things to a colleague, [Talk to the Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 5):

An unquantified CNF formula consisting of clauses containing a single positive literal plus any number of negated literals is always satisfiable.  To produce a satisfying assignment, you simply set all the positive literals to true, satisfying all the clauses.  If you existentially quantify the variables associated with the positive literals and allow arbitrary quantification of the remaining variables, the formula is still satisfiable, and  for the same reason.  In the proof of the theorem, $P_\mathit{\Phi}$ is the subset of such clauses from the Horn formula $\mathit{\Phi}$.  Thus $P_\mathit{\Phi}$ by itself is always satisfiable.  It follows that $\mathit{\Phi}$ can only be unsatisfiable if, out of the sets of remaining clauses (denoted $N^+_\mathit{\Phi}$ and $N_\mathit{\Phi}$), a clause requires one of the previously set positive literals in $P_\mathit{\Phi}$ to be set false and there is no other way to satisfy the previously satisfied clause.